# Игра пятнашки, перемещение блоков

Tags: javascript, html, css

Добрый день уважаемые программисты, нужна помощь с перемещением кнопок. Вы наверняка слышали про игру "Пятнашки", я создал рандомизацию чисел. Они распределяются по кнопкам. Но как сделать так, чтобы кнопки двигались в пустое место. Для многих это глупый вопрос, но я только начинаю вникать в эту среду и прошу о помощи. Заранее вам спасибо.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var arr2 = []
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button')

function getrandom() 
{
  while (true)
  {
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
    if (!arr2.includes(num))
    {
      arr2.push(num)
      return num
    }
  }
}

function pushrand()
{
  buttons.forEach(element => 
  {
    let random = getrandom()
    element.innerHTML = arr[random]
  })
  arr2 = [];
}
```

```css
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    height: 100%;
}
.container{
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.buttons {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    gap: 1rem;
}

.button {
    width: 10rem;
    height: 10rem;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
}

button{
    font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="wclassth=device-wclassth, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Пятнашки</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button class="block1" onclick = pushrand()><span class="randNumbers">Новая игра</span>
    </button>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="game">
            <div class="buttons">
                <button class="button"></button>
                <button class="button"></button>
                <button class="button"></button>
                <button class="button"></button>
                <button class="button"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Мы ничего не поняли, так как мы тут на русском общаемся ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Добрый день уважаемые программисты, нужна помощь с перемещением кнопок. Вы наверняка слышали про игру "Пятнашки", я создал рандомизацию чисел. Они распределяются по кнопкам. Но как сделать так, чтобы кнопки двигались в пустое место. Для многих это глупый вопрос, но я только начинаю вникать в эту среду и прошу о помощи. Заранее вам спасибо.

Comment: Извините,просто мне друг сказал, что за русские темы банят)))

Comment: ну, это RUso, а не ENso. Поэтому тут как раз на русском. А вот на en - на английском

Comment: Хорошо, буду знать, не знаете решение проблемы, а то идей у меня нет...(((

Answer (score 3):

Мой ответ намеренно не содержит весь нужный вам код, но основные принципы и подсказки я предоставил. Успехов в освоении программирования!

**Математические обоснования:**

Игра пятнашки подразумевает то что ее можно в итоге собрать, в Вашем конкретном случае это не гарантируется, человек может биться головой об стену но не решит. Поэтому рандом может быть, но по правилам (тоже через движения)

Подробнее можно посмотреть [видео урок](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZthXsFcFLo)  известного российского математика Алексея Саватеева

**Двумерный массив в качестве структуры данных:**

Так же эта игра 2-мерная, нужно использовать двумерный массив для простоты оценки координат и отображения.

Таким образом общая логика выглядит так:

1. делаете верстку используя либо таблицу, либо грид, либо 4 флексбокса, в общем на вкус.
2. создаете начальный массив

Например:

```
 const board = [
  [1,2,3,4],
  [5,6,7,8],
  [9,10,11,12],
  [13,14,15,0]
 ]
```

Тут `0` отвечает за пустую ячейку - удобно пользоваться только цифрами. Что касается легальных движений то на нулевую ячеку в данном случае можно переставить фигуру либо сверху либо слева (снизу и справа нет доски) Таким образом вам нужно совершить перестановку.

**Базовое осуществление ходов:**

Перестановка сверху будет выглядеть так:

```
const temp = board[2][3];  // запомнили 12
board[2][3] = board[3][3]; // поставили 0 на место 12 
board[3][3] = temp; // поставили 12 на место 0
```

А перестановка слева так:

```
const temp = board[3][2];  // запомнили 15
board[3][2] = board[3][3]; // поставили 0 на место 15 
board[3][3] = temp; // поставили 15 на место 0
```

Вам не составит труда написать код для еще двух перестановок.

Итак используя функцию проверки валидности кода (которую Вам еще предстоит написать) и функцию перестановки Вы сможете правильно перемешать фигуры. Далее используя эти же функции можно позволить игроку играть.

Например если движение осуществляется по клику на фигуру, то нужно убедится что рядом с ней есть 0, но не по диагонали, иначе ничего не делать.

Убедившись что 0 есть рядом вы уже можете сделать ход.

**Как я предлагаю вам организовать это в HTML:**

Пусть у нас будет 16 ячеек и мы их будем заполнять цифрами, у каждой ячейки мы можем добавить `data-x` `data-y` атрибуты - это координаты в массиве и мы будем знать на что нажал игрок.

А так же при перестановке мы можем менять значения только в них, не отрисовывая все заново (тоже Вам реализовать)

**Пример:**

Приведу небольшой пример, чтобы не сильно Вас баловать и дать возможность чему-то научиться сделав игру самостоятельно.

По поводу изначального смешивания - вы знаете всегда где находится 0 просто двигайте его туда где есть фигуры (программно определяя куда он может пойти) сделав 100 таких ходов случайно вы осуществите правильное перемешивание.

```js
const rows = [
  document.getElementById('row1').children,
  document.getElementById('row2').children
]
const myBoard = document.getElementById('board')

const board = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 0]
]

function drawAll(){
  for (let y = 0 ; y < 2; y++)
    for (let x = 0 ; x < 2; x++){
      rows[y][x].textContent = board[y][x] ? board[y][x] : '';
      rows[y][x].dataset.x = x;
      rows[y][x].dataset.y = y;
      if (board[y][x] === 0){
        rows[y][x].classList.add('empty')
      } else {
        rows[y][x].classList.remove('empty')
      }
    }
}

drawAll();

function getEmptyCellCoordinates(){
  let x = -1
  let y = -1
  for (let row = 0;  row < 2;  row++){
    y = row; // строка всегда соответсвует `y` 
    x = board[row].indexOf(0) // x будет -1 если не найдена колонка с 0
    if (x != -1) break // нашли 0
  }
  return {y, x}
}

myBoard.addEventListener('click', (event)=> {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'BUTTON'){
    const from = {y: event.target.dataset.y, x: event.target.dataset.x};
    const to = getEmptyCellCoordinates();
    console.clear();
    console.log(`выбранная ячейка была ${from.y}, ${from.x}`);
    console.log(`пустая ячейка была: ${to.y}, ${to.x}`);
    move(from, to);
  }
}, false) 

function validate( from, to){
   // проверка валидности хода
   // ячейки должны быть поблизости,
   // но не по диагонали друг к другу
   // сейчас работает и по диагонали
   // подсказка:
   // по одной из координат ячейки должны полностью совпадать
   // по другой разница должна быть не больше 1 (с любым знаком + или -) 
   return true // если ход не возможен возвращаем falsе
}

function move( from, to){
  if (validate(from, to)){
    const temp = board[from.y][from.x]
    board[from.y][from.x] = board[to.y][to.x]
    board[to.y][to.x] = temp
    // отрисовываем либо все либо только изменения
    drawAll() // в данном пример все (излишне)
  }
}
```

```css
div[id^=row] {
  display: flex;
}

button  {
  height:32px;
  width: 32px;
  margin: 1px;
}

button.empty {
  background: grey;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="board">
  <div id="row1">
    <button> </button><button> </button>
  </div>
  <div id="row2" >
    <button> </button><button> </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Приведенный код далеко не идеальный, например, координаты пустой ячейки можно хранить в переменной, убедившись что Ваш код работает можете приступать к оптимизации.